# Can not get an error response after calling the api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't get the error details.

```
testSchema
      .validate(createValidationData, { abortEarly: false })
      .then(() => {
        const user= ...
        Service.postApiAddTest(user)
          .then(() => {
            //...
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.response);// here response is undefined
        
          });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

I can get the result of error.message and it throws an internal server error, but when I try to get the response it's undefined.

however, I can see the response in the browser
[image]

Edit 1:

```
    public static postApiAddTest(
requestBody?: TestObject,
): CancelablePromise<any> {
        return __request(OpenAPI, {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/addTest',
            body: requestBody,
            mediaType: 'application/json',
        });
    }
```

Comment: maybe because... it's undefined? What did u get when u do console.log(error) ?

Comment: please write function code of Service.postApiAddTest. to work correctly, it must return a promise

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue and I had to get the response body like this:

```
.catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.body);
```